# Rails ActiveRecord Timezone for a single table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Almost all of my tables uses UTC.
However some legacy table uses EST.

I live in EST. so I set

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

So far so good, data is stored in UTC and translated to EST

However, when I handle some legacy tables, 
I want to have data stored in EST and translated as it is in EST, I can set;

```
config.active_record.time_zone = :local
```

but, applies to all models and it breaks a lot of tests.

Is there a way to set timezone for each model?

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you set the active_record.time_zone to :local and use [Time.zone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) for store the data in EST it will help you...